# How do you specify a main class in a manifest file when compiling from the parent directory?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, javac

My directory structure is like this:

```
> makefile
> app.jar
> src
    > Main.java
    > Main.class
    > some other classes
    > manifest.txt
```

I compile from the makefile with these commands:

```
javac src/*.java
jar cvfm app.jar src/manifest.txt src/*.class
```

`manifest.txt` contains this:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

When I run `java -jar app.jar` from the top directory I get this error:

```
$ java -jar app.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit.
```

I tried changing the manifest to say `Main-Class: src.Main` but that didn't work either.  This is probably very simple but I'm finding Google doesn't provide any simple solutions.

Comment: Did you check that generated `jar` contains `Main` class inside?

Comment: I think jar should be invoked as `jar cvfm app.jar src/manifest.txt -C src *.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the answer from Oracle

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Please find the sample code:-

```
package oata
public class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
 }
```

Create a folder to place the .class file
Then compile the and run the file.

```
 `md build\classes
   javac -sourcepath src -d build\classes src\oata\HelloWorld.java
  java -cp build\classes oata.HelloWorld`


  `echo Main-Class: oata.HelloWorld>myManifest
     md build\jar
    jar cfm build\jar\HelloWorld.jar myManifest -C build\classes .
    java -jar build\jar\HelloWorld.jar`
```

Thanks
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NoClassDefFoundError exception, might be class-path is not set properly.

Thanks,
Pavan